# php unset using loop

Tags: php, for-loop

why I cant get the result I want with this code?

```
for($i=0; $i<count($results); $i++){
                            if($results[$i]->high == $results[$i]->open and $results[$i]->low == $results[$i]->close and $results[$i]->vol == 0){
                                unset($results[$i]);    
                        }
echo json_encode($results);
```

why I still get the same result as if the unset inside the loop not working? but if I call the echo inside the loop its work

Comment: What is the result you want? Your question is not very clear about what you are actually trying to do.

Comment: could you give us a sample of `$results`, so we can replicate and possibly help find a solution? Btw, you did not close the `}` of the `for` loop.

Comment: hi @berend the result is somewhat like this{"code":"TLKM","_date":"2020-11-09","_time":"09:17:00","open":2890,"high":2890,"low":2880,"close":2890,"vol":260100}
{"code":"TLKM","_date":"2020-11-09","_time":"09:18:00","open":2880,"high":2890,"low":2880,"close":2880,"vol":288300}
{"code":"TLKM","_date":"2020-11-09","_time":"09:19:00","open":2890,"high":2890,"low":2880,"close":2890,"vol":3070200}

i want to remove some of them using for loop. but if i call the result outside the loop it looks like the code work asynchronous, so the result show original result without the unset

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the sample json data you provided, I've added a `DUMMY` record that matches the conditions in the `if`, so it will be `unset` as follows:

```
<?php
$json = '[
   {
      "code":"TLKM",
      "_date":"2020-11-09",
      "_time":"09:17:00",
      "open":2890,
      "high":2890,
      "low":2880,
      "close":2890,
      "vol":260100
   },
   {
      "code":"TLKM",
      "_date":"2020-11-09",
      "_time":"09:18:00",
      "open":2880,
      "high":2890,
      "low":2880,
      "close":2880,
      "vol":288300
   },
   {
      "code":"DUMMIE",
      "_date":"2020-11-09",
      "_time":"09:19:00",
      "open":2890,
      "high":2890,
      "low":2880,
      "close":2880,
      "vol":0
   },
   {
      "code":"TLKM",
      "_date":"2020-11-09",
      "_time":"09:19:00",
      "open":2890,
      "high":2890,
      "low":2880,
      "close":2890,
      "vol":3070200
   }
]';

// turn json into associative array
$arr = json_decode($json, true);

// process the array
foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
    if ($arr[$key]['high'] == $arr[$key]['open'] and $arr[$key]['low'] == $arr[$key]['close'] and $arr[$key]['vol'] == 0) {
        unset($arr[$key]);
    }
}

// array back to json format
$json = json_encode($arr);
```

Have a look at the [demo](https://3v4l.org/jWs94)

Output:

```
{
    "0": {
        "code": "TLKM",
        "_date": "2020-11-09",
        "_time": "09:17:00",
        "open": 2890,
        "high": 2890,
        "low": 2880,
        "close": 2890,
        "vol": 260100
    },
    "1": {
        "code": "TLKM",
        "_date": "2020-11-09",
        "_time": "09:18:00",
        "open": 2880,
        "high": 2890,
        "low": 2880,
        "close": 2880,
        "vol": 288300
    },
    "3": {
        "code": "TLKM",
        "_date": "2020-11-09",
        "_time": "09:19:00",
        "open": 2890,
        "high": 2890,
        "low": 2880,
        "close": 2890,
        "vol": 3070200
    }
}
```